# JSON <=> Java Object Mapper which translates well with J2objc

Tags: java, android, objective-c, json, j2objc

I use the `org.json.*` classes which are part of the j2objc distribution. The mapping of my DTO classes and the JSON Objects are made by hand so far. 
I know there is GSOn and Jackson.

**Is there a JSON to Object Mapper library which translates well with J2objc and works well in the translated Objective-C code?**

Comment: Do you want to map `json` object to `java` object ?

Comment: @Paritosh yes json to java and java to json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson and GSON are the two best libraries, and both have been translated using j2objc for iOS apps from different teams (no public ports that I'm aware of, though).

If you control the server-side of the app, though, [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) are generally faster than any JSON->Java alternative. That is why they're used by most of Google's iOS apps, including Inbox and Sheets that use j2objc. [j2objc now publicly supports protocol buffers](https://github.com/google/j2objc/wiki/Using-Protocol-Buffers).

Answer (score 0):

To convert `json` data to `java` object you can use:

1. [Jackson](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-introduction.jsp)
2. [Gson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson)

Follow [this link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) or [this link](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON) for nice `GSON` tutorial.

I personally used `GSON`, and it is best library for `json` to `java object` conversion.

I don't know about conversion part of `j2objc` but you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21445299/3843374), if you want to do similar thing with `iOS` code

***Edit***

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19302565/3843374), `j2objc` requires source code for conversion. You will get full source code from [here](https://github.com/google/gson).

Now, the important part, `Gson` can be converted to `j2objc` and you can find test repository to test support for `gson-2.3` with `j2objc` [here](https://github.com/foens/gson-2.3-j2objc-test).

Comment: Not related to my question!

Comment: Check ***Edit*** part